# Good match test (good fit test) - How to solve?

Tags: testing-and-verification

please advise me with this example. The solution should be done using the program wolfram mathematica. But I do not know how. Can you please advise me?

Parents with blood group AB have children with blood groups AA, AB, BB. If the Mendelian inheritance hypothesis is true, then these blood groups should be present in a proportion of 25%, 50% and 25% in the offspring. The following table shows the blood groups of 284 children whose parents had blood groups AB. Do these data at the significance level of 0.05 confirm Mendel's hypothesis?

I have to do a job about good match (fit?) test. Do you know any website on this topic? Unfortunately, I do not know how to perform these tests in the program.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: It looks like you are staking a stats class? No doubt your teacher has supplied some resources about how to carry out statistical tests. Mathematica has a number of functions that carry out such calculations, for instance type ?Hypoth* and follow through to the guide on Statistical Testing

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no information. At this time we have self-study.